# Lock mobile to ARFCN

Tags: at-command, qualcomm

I'm working on a project which I want to control a Qualcomm chip-set mobile with AT-commands.

I made some initial progress with the supported AT-commands, but found out that these are very limited in getting the Informations we are interested in.

The only thing I got stuck with: I can't figure out how to lock the mobile to a given ARFCN.

Is there a hidden AT Command, or do I have to send a specific command to the Qualcomm Diagnostics port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid there is no way to set particular ARFCN via AT on ‘non-dev’ soft. However, you can try to manipulate with **NV items** on your Qualcomm device (I set bands via **QXDM** on various commercial LTE devices).

You can also change **NV items** via DIAG. This can be helpful - [DIAG_QCDM](https://moonsky219.github.io/post/diag_qcdm/)